# Sending a basic 1D array in winsock through TCP

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

Im trying send an array of uint8_t in the lenght of 10 through TCP connection using Winsock send() function. It seems like that it doesn't send anything. What's wrong with the procedure ?.

```
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 10

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET server_socket, client_socket;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
int c, iResult;
char sendbuf [DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int sendbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
uint8_t* p;

// Send string to client
p = (uint8_t*)sendbuf;

p[0] = 67;
p[1] = 143;
p[2] = 222;
p[3] = 134;
p[4] = 217;
p[5] = 97;
p[6] = 17;
p[7] = 16;
p[8] = 181;
p[9] = 137;
iResult = send(client_socket, sendbuf, sendbuflen, 0);

// shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
if (shutdown(client_socket, SD_SEND) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
{
    printf("Shutdown failed. Error Code : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    iResult = 1;
}

closesocket(client_socket);
WSACleanup();

return iResult;
}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you connect to the server?

Comment: I didn't add that part, as I don't have any problems to connect with the client. I managed to send a single string to the client from this program, so the connection is ok.

Comment: The question is more like, whether this can send this array or not

Comment: try to init sendbuf as `unsigned char`.

Comment: When I do this, I get this following error: 
"argument of type "unsigned char* is incompatible with parameter type "const char*"

Comment: What happens when you do `char sendbuf[10] = {67,143,222,134,217,97,17,16,181,137};` instead of all that other stuff? I do think it's worth showing how you connect... so people can reproduce your code. In other words - show all the lines of code that between them get you the error. Maybe the "successfully sent a string" caused the connection to be closed, for example...

Comment: "It seems like that it doesn't send anything" "I managed to send a single string to the client" What symptoms indicate that the array of long are not being sent? Have you considered endianness if sending to a different platform? I think we are still missing elements necessary to help you. I suggest you post both client and server code.

Comment: What is the value of iResult after the send() call? send() returns the number of bytes actually sent (which might be less than sendbuflen) or -1 if an error occurred.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. The c-code is actual fine. It was the client that actually was configured as a different data type. I'm receiving the correct array now.